# Functions equivalent to pattern matching on ADTs

Tags: language-agnostic, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types

Is there some minimal set of functions which together form an equivalent to pattern matching on ADTs?

I'm particularly interested if there are proofs that they're equivalent.

Comment: I don't think that's possible because the whole purpose of pattern matching is to allow the existence of ADTs by discriminating the sum types.